# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat. Using jsp file

Tags: spring, jsp, tomcat, classpath

I get this error when running my project as a Spring Boot App, my guess is that the solution might not be too complicated:

**Log of the error:**

```
2021-03-05 12:53:10.041  INFO 4704 --- [           main] .s.M13SimpleSpringHttpServiceApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-03-05 12:53:10.936  INFO 4704 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-03-05 12:53:10.954  INFO 4704 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 7 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-03-05 12:53:11.520  WARN 4704 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.isGraalAvailable()'
2021-03-05 12:53:11.531  INFO 4704 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-03-05 12:53:11.552 ERROR 4704 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.<clinit>(Tomcat.java:1303)

The following method did not exist:

    'boolean org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.isGraalAvailable()'

The method's class, org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util/8.5.30/tomcat-util-8.5.30.jar!/org/apache/tomcat/util/compat/JreCompat.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.43/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/org/apache/tomcat/util/compat/JreCompat.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat: file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util/8.5.30/tomcat-util-8.5.30.jar

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat
```

**POM file**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
        
    <groupId>com.simpleSpringHTTPService</groupId>
    <artifactId>M13SimpleSpringHTTPService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>M13SimpleSpringHTTPService</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
   
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
   
   </project>
```

**jsp file inside: src/main/webApp  folder**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <form action="addEmployee">
        <input type="text" name="id"><br>
        <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
        <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
        <input type="text" name="job_role"><br>
        <input type="submit"><br>
        
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Employee Class**

```java
    package com.simpleSpringHTTPService.model;
    
    public class Employee {
    
        private String first_name;
        private String last_name;
        private String job_role;
        private int id;
        
        public String getFirst_name() {
            return first_name;
        }
        public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
            this.first_name = first_name;
        }
        public String getLast_name() {
            return last_name;
        }
        public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
            this.last_name = last_name;
        }
        public String getJob_role() {
            return job_role;
        }
        public void setJob_role(String job_role) {
            this.job_role = job_role;
        }
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Employee [first_name=" + first_name + ", last_name=" + last_name + ", job_role=" + 
            job_role + ", id="+ id + "]";
        }   
        
    }
```

**EmployeeController Class**

```java
    package com.simpleSpringHTTPService.controller;
    
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    
    @Controller
    public class EmployeeController {
    
        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String home() {
            
            return "home.jsp";
        }
    }
```

I am aware that this does not do much yet, but I would like to run it and open http://localhost:8080 and see the result.

I have tried to look into the buildpath libraries as described in other threads like: [disableRegistry() doesn't exist (org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60833809/disableregistry-doesnt-exist-org-apache-tomcat-util-modeler-registry), but i would not want to mess with it too much as I am new to this, any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You put two incompatible versions of `tomcat-util` among your dependencies:

- a version 9.0.43 is contained in [`tomcat-embed-core`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.43), which is a transitive dependency of [`spring-boot-starter-web`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.4.3),
- a version 8.5.30 is a transitive dependency of [`tomcat-jasper`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper/8.5.35), which you added separately.

You should use [`embed-tomcat-jasper`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/9.0.43) instead, version 9.0.43. Maven tries to eliminate version conflicts as best as it can, but it doesn't know that `tomcat-jasper` and `embed-tomcat-jasper` are the same thing. Since `spring-boot-starter-parent` manages Tomcat's version, you can (and probably should) omit the version declaration:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>embed-tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed the dependency to:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.43</version>
</dependency>  instead of <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.30</version>
</dependency>
And it is running, don't quite understand yet the difference between embed-tomcat-jasper and tomcat-jasper, but this will do for now, thanks a million!