# Spring boot app not starting with embedded erver

Tags: spring-boot

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:183)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.disableRegistry()V
```

Maven clean install not working

Pom.Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>boot.practice</groupId>
<artifactId>config</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>config</name>
<description>practice project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: So you are deploying the WAR to tomcat?

Comment: run on server works but run as javaapplication gives the above error

Comment: I copied your pom.xml and it works for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [disableRegistry() doesn't exist (org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60833809/disableregistry-doesnt-exist-org-apache-tomcat-util-modeler-registry)

Comment: @rogerdpack yes it did help.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve it . The problem was that the spring boot 2.5.0 was using tomcat 9.0.46 by default while my system had tomcat 9.0.0.M15 . So when I ran the application as "run on server" the tomcat 9.0.0.m15 added to my class path and then when ever I was doing  run as java applicationit was throwing the error. Clearing the tomcat embedded repo from .M2 path and updating the local system with tomcat 9.0.46 fixed the problem